# AWS Cloud S3 and Retrieve the file using Tableau

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, tableau-api, amazon-athena

In an S3 bucket, we have a path structure with "Roll number" as the folder name and all the answer sheet files are stored as documents under this name.
An example structure is below:

```
Studentdocument (bucketname)
  2011022324 (roll number)
    Folder1/PDF1 (document)
    Folder2/PDF2
    Folder3/PDF3 
    Folder4/PDF4 
    Folder5/PDF5
  2012324232 (roll number)        
    Folder1/PDF1 
    Folder2/PDF2
    Folder3/PDF3  
    Folder4/PDF4  
    Folder5/PDF5
```

All the roll numbers are stored with the same structure as above.

We would like to retrieve these PDF documents when roll number is provided as the input. Tableau is the reporting tool which will pass this input.

One of the options we have considered is to store meta data in Athena and create the signed URL and provide to user, but currently Athena is not an approved service in our organisation.

What other options exist to retrieve this PDF document when roll number passed as the input?

We could use the signed URL concept and that will be created in Lambda, but we would like to know what options exist to trigger a lambda function.

Comment: It's not clear to me if your question is "how do I generate S3 pre-signed URLs for a number of PDF documents" or "how do I trigger Lambda to generate S3 pre-signed URLs" or both.

Comment: Question is:  Using Athena lambda can be triggered. (I.e Tableau - Athena - Lambda). But now Athena is not approved service in our organization. So what is the option tableau trigger the lambda function